# ESLint experimentalObjectRestSpread not applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, babeljs

ESLint is still throwing `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ..` and I can't seem to figure out why.

`.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: "devmountain/react-config"
    , rules: {
        quotes: [ 1, "double" ]
    }
    , "ecmaVersion": 6
    , "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
};
```

Extending from [here](https://github.com/DevMountain/eslint-config-devmountain)

And the code in question: `this.setState( { ...this.state, editorState } );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ecmaFeatures` and `ecmaVersion` options go under [`parserOptions`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options). For example:

```
...
"extends": "devmountain/react-config",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 6
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In v6.0.0 (and above), the deprecated experimentalObjectRestSpread option has been [removed](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-6.0.0#experimental-object-rest-spread)

This is the new code:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018
  }
}
```